# remove trailing 'z' from UTC ISO midnight date to get local

Tags: javascript, date

How can I remove trailing 'z' from UTC ISO date to get local date?

```
var dateNow = new Date();
dateNow.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
var dateToISO = dateNow.toISOString();
```

The above code gives result like this - 2017-07-14T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: `dateToISO = dateToISO.replace(/Z$/, "")`

Comment: You can always trim off the last character using simple JS functions.

Comment: Simply removing the Z doesn't give a local date, the UTC date is different to the local date for the period of the timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an intermediate variable with some simple js calls.

```
var temp = dateNow.toISOString();
var dateToISO  =  temp.substr(0,temp.length -1)
```

If only your simple motive is to drop the trailing 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

```
const localDate = dateToISO.substring(0, dataToISO.length - 1);
```